# Gnome finds no audio devices

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, audio

I've installed ArchLinux on a Dell XPS 15 L521X. For some reason when Gnome boots it finds no audio devices.

[image: no audio devices found]

If I switch to a virtual terminal and use the terminal based music player `cmus` to play some music, all of a sudden they appear.

[image: audio devices appear after playing music in cmus]

The devices in question:

```
mike@longshot:~☺  lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e1b] (rev ff)
```

Interestingly, even running that `lspci -nn | grep -i audio` command causes Gnome to suddenly find the audio devices.

How can I get Gnome to reliably find these devices by itself on startup?

Comment: I believe what you see is PulseAudio *volume control*. What PA gives you, I think, is the devices *when they're used*. If you want to see what devices were *detected*, check `alsamixer` in any terminal or run any other *mixer* GUI.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I disabled my audio in the BIOS started my system, shut down and enabled the audio again in the BIOS. After that I did two cold boots and the audio started working again. Oh and in the meantime I also blacklisted my hardware beep because it was so annoying but I doubt that had anything to do with it.